# How do I use "COUNTIFS" in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to add a `COUNTIFS` formula to cells in `openpyexcel` and am not able to because of the string and the way that Excel needs to format the formula. I have tried wrapping the formula in triple equals (`""" <formula string> """`), escaping the quotation with `\`, and tried using `f"{var}"` strings. I also tried to reference the documentation for parsing formulae, but found it confusing.

My current code:

```
supervisor_sheet['C2'].value = "=COUNTIFS('Act RTB'!E:E,Supervisor!A2,'Act RTB'!I:I,("On Time")"
supervisor_sheet['D2'].value = "=COUNTIFS('Act RTB'!E:E,Supervisor!A2,'Act RTB'!I:I,("Late")"
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way!

Using `+` and putting the latter string in single quotes

```
supervisor_sheet['C2'].value = "=COUNTIFS('Act RTB'!E:E,Supervisor!A2,'Act RTB'!I:I"+',"On Time")'
supervisor_sheet['D2'].value = "=COUNTIFS('Act RTB'!E:E,Supervisor!A2,'Act RTB'!I:I"+',"Late")'
```

Comment: You don't need to use `+` operator if you properly escape your quoted strings :) like: `"=COUNTIFS('Act RTB'!E:E,Supervisor!A2,'Act RTB'!I:I,\"On Time\")"`

Comment: Or, use single-quotes within the doublequoted stirng: `"=COUNTIFS('Act RTB'!E:E,Supervisor!A2,'Act RTB'!I:I,'On Time')"`. This is, incidentally, what you previously did with the worksheet name where it is given as a range qualifier `'Act RTB'!E:E`, etc.